# How do I forget a move learned by TM? Or are they permanent?

Tags: pokemon-uranium

My pokemon learned Rock Smash from a TM.

I'm trying to learn Brick Break from another TM but I want to replace Rock Smash.

Apparently I can't forget Rock Smash.

So, are TM moves permanent or there is a way to forget them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rock Smash is a [HM move](http://pokemon-uranium.wikia.com/wiki/TM_and_HM_list#List_of_HMs).

You need to talk to the [Move Deleter in Venesia](http://pokemon-uranium.wikia.com/wiki/Venesi_City#The_Move_Expert.2C_Move_Deleter.2C_and_Move_Tutor) (after the fifth gym) to forget that move.

Comment: Dammit! I just finished the 2nd gym and it took 10 game hours! It will take a lifetime to forget that move! That's the kind of info that should be warned before we commit to it.

Comment: @vianna77 In all fairness, that is exactly how it is in official Pokemon games as well. HMs cannot be forgotten except by the Move Deleter, and he typically becomes available in the latter half of the game. There's also really no warning in the official games about this restriction either... I'm not saying it's right, I'm just saying uranium seems to be on par with the official games in this regard! :)

Comment: @king14nyr I was just letting off some steam because I added that move to my only Shiny Pokemon :'(  I'm new to the pokemon universe and the uranium is consuming a great deal of my day :D What an addictive game!!!